# How to show the gradient annotator for dynamic symbol instances in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to use the gradient annotator on a path in a dynamic symbol in illustrator. I can't seem to get the gradient annotator to appear. Is this possible, and if not, are there any workarounds? It's very limiting to  not be able to modify the gradient in a dynamic symbol instance.

Comment: I can't replicate this problem.  If I double click a dynamic symbol to edit it, the gradient annotator works as expected.

Comment: The downvote is not appreciated. I'm talking about an ___instance___ of a dynamic symbol, wherein which you must use the direct selection tool to modify the appearance of a component in that dynamic symbol. For these, there is no gradient annotator. Modifying the master dynamic symbol itself has the annotator as expected, but not the instances.

Answer (score 1):

- If you don't see the **Gradient Annotator**, check its visibility at
  **Menu View** > **Show/Hide Gradient Annotator**
- To make changes in a Symbol, click twice the Symbol to edit
- The Gradient "Annotator" does not work for strokes, it is only for
  filling

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I am only interested in the annotator for the fill in a particular shape in an instance of a dynamic symbol. It doesn't seem to show up there, so; for radial gradients, I cannot determine their shape.